# PHP Output pre_replace_callback

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I'm a php coding newbie, I want to output the first and the third matches. The below code is my coding so far.

```
$string="[nextpage] This is first text
[nextpage] This is the second text
[nextpage] This is the third text";
$string = preg_replace_callback("/\[nextpage\]([^\[nextpage\]]*)(.*?)(\n|\r\n?)/is", function ($submatch) {
    static $matchcount = 0;
    $matchcount++;
    $rtt=$submatch[2];
    return "<li>$rtt</li>";
  }, $string);
echo $string; //This is first text
                This is the second text
                This is the third text
```

I've tried outputting `$rtt=$submatch[0][1];` to get the first match and `$rtt=$submatch[0][3];` to get the third match but doesn't work.

Expected results;

```
//This is first text
  This is the third text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `$matchcount` to test which match it is.

Also, matching `\r` and `\n` won't match the end of the last line, since there's no newline after them. You also need to match `$`, which is the end of the string.

`([^\[nextpage\]]*)` is totally unnecessary, and doesn't do what you probably think it does. `[^string]` doesn't mean to not match that string, it matches any single character that isn't one of those characters.

```
$string = preg_replace_callback("/\[nextpage\]([^\r\n]*)(\n|\r\n?|$)/is", function ($submatch) {
    static $matchcount = 0;
    $matchcount++;
    if ($matchcount == 1 || $matchcount == 3) {
        $rtt=$submatch[1];
        return "<li>$rtt</li>";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
  }, $string);
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/DQDUS43387)

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. This solved my problem.

Comment: Please @barmar how do i get the total matches for the regex i tried `count($submatch)` but doesn't work.

Comment: You could make `$matchcount` a global variable, it will then contain the number of matches.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a different approach is in order?

You can split the string into an array and then pick the pieces you care about.

```
<?php
$string="[nextpage] This is first text
[nextpage] This is the second text
[nextpage] This is the third text";

$explosion = explode('[nextpage] ', $string);
var_dump($explosion);
$textICareAbout = trim($explosion[1]) . "  " . trim($explosion[3]);

echo $textICareAbout;
```

**Yields**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(20) "This is first text
"
  [2]=>
  string(25) "This is the second text
"
  [3]=>
  string(22) "This is the third text"
}

This is first text  This is the third text
```

Comment: I want the output to be inside the `preg_replace_callback` because i will be using the output for some other things. Anyway, @Barmar answer solved my problem. Thanks for the contribution.